# How to loop through a catpart in Catia

Tags: .net, cad, catia

I'm new to programming with the Catia APIs. I would like to know if, given a catpart, is there a way in .NET to extract the following information from it:

- body
- faces
- loops
- edge

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Which information do you want to extract from e.g. a body? Name of the body (the bodies), count of bodies, dimensions, geometric / mathematical description. Depending on your requirements the answer can be yes or no. Please ask more precisely.

Comment: Hi, I need to get all the possible information from the part\assembly to convert it into our format. about the models I need to know the list of faces and edges. For each face and edge the topology and the data (radius of cilyinder, points of nurbs ecc..) so that I can use to recreate it into my kernel. Is it possible? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to discover and list faces, edges and vertexes. However what you are allowed to see is not very useful as the internal naming conventions are very complex. As for underlying math there is no part of the API which lets you have access to that.

You will have to use IGES or STEP to get the level of information you require.